# Expressing a Stack ADT with a Finite State Machine Diagram

Tags: stack, diagram, finite-automata, state-machine, abstract-data-type

I'm trying to use a finite state machine diagram to represent the Stack abstract data type, and I'm struggling to find a way to represent an unbounded alphabet. A stack can have an infinite number elements, but I can't draw infinite states in my diagram.

The solution I'm leaning toward is to use recursion, but I can't find any examples of expressing recursion in a finite state machine **diagram**. Is there a standard way to draw a recursion? Or is there another solution to my infinity problem?

Comment: Like you said, a stack is not a finite state machine, so why are you doing this exercise in the first place? There is a finite state machine called a "Push-down automaton" which utilizes a stack to store some of its state in addition to the machine's states. Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: I was doing this for a school assignment, and a finite state machine is definitely what I was looking for. I'm confused too.

Answer (score 0):

The machine model that corresponds to  a stack is the push-down automaton. This model is known to be more powerful than finite state machines. Thus it is impossible to represent a stack with the latter. There is no solution to your problem.

You do not have an *unbounded alphabet*, though. Only the number of symbols on the stack is unbounded.